# A doubt about analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function and $f:=u+iv$. Then is it always true  that $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$ ?

Comment: You know that analytic functions satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, right? Take those and try to proceed from there.

Comment: But for that we need $v_{xy}$ and $v_{yx}$ to be continous, is that always true ?

Comment: An analytic function is a power series, and thus its derivatives are all smooth.

Comment: I got the answer. In wikipedia I saw that analytic functions are infinitely differentiable. Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: @pritam, we need to assume $u_{xy}=u_{yx}$ and $v_{xy}=v_{yx}$, right? I'd like to know in what condition $f_{xy}≠f_{yx}$ and when they coincide.

Comment: @lab $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ when they are both continous. See here :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Clairaut.27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Analytic function satisfies Cauchy Riemann  equation.

i.e.

$u_{x}=v_{y}$  &  $u_{y}=-v_{x}$

so, $u_{xx}=v_{xy}$ &  $u_{yy}=-v_{yx}$

so, $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0\ when\ v_{xy}=v_{yx}$